# iptables: No chain/target/match by that name

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to set iptables on Debian 6 Squeeze amd64 and I'm faced to this error message

```
root@Vision:~/bin# iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

I searched on the web but I didn't find a solution. Other rules gives me same error.

Comment: can you post the output of the `iptables-save` command?

Comment: ... also post the output of `find /lib -name "*conntrack.ko"` please.

Answer (score 2):

your kernel needs the netfilter module conntrack

```
Location:                                                                                                                                          │  
  │     -> Networking support (NET [=y])                                                                                                                 │  
  │       -> Networking options                                                                                                                          │  
  │         -> Network packet filtering framework (Netfilter) (NETFILTER [=y])                                                                           │  
  │           -> Core Netfilter Configuration                                                                                                            │  
  │             -> Netfilter Xtables support (required for ip_tables) (NETFILTER_XTABLES [=m])
```

Answer (score 2):

check the dmesg output for the actual error also run the rule with strace to get the missing modules

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your kernel is missing some Netfilter features.
You need the Xtables support, as Fabio pointed out. However, you need the xt_conntrack feature as well. It might be compiled as a module, so that entering the command you wrote should load it. But in some cases, you'll need to load it by yourself so, before going further, try

```
# modprobe xt_conntrack
```

If it doesn't work, you'll have to recompile your kernel to enable it.
You can find the option here:

```
Symbol: NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNTRACK                                                                                                                                                     
│   Depends on: NET [=y] && INET [=y] && NETFILTER [=y] && NETFILTER_XTABLES [=y] &&      NF_CONNTRACK [=y]                                                                                               
│   Location:                                                                                                                                                                                   
│     -> Networking support (NET [=y])                                                                                                                                                            
│       -> Networking options                                                                                                                                                                   
│         -> Network packet filtering framework (Netfilter) (NETFILTER [=y])                                                                                                                       
│           -> Core Netfilter Configuration                                                                                                                                                      
│             -> Netfilter Xtables support (required for ip_tables) (NETFILTER_XTABLES [=y])
```

If you're not familiar with kernel building, you might want to have a look at the book at http://www.kroah.com/lkn/ which explains all you need to know from the start in a very clear fashion.

(I know this is a bit late to answer. Still, I've faced the same issue today so I thought it might help someone someday.)