# iptables: No chain/target/match by that name. Ubuntu 16-04 (WSL2)

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-16.04

I know, there are many questions with this topic, but none of them helps me.

After I run
`sudo iptables -w -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 100.64.0.8 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 25119`

I get `iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.`

I was following [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/524471/1005876) to identify the part of the rule that causes the error. I have discovered that if I run `sudo iptables -w -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 100.64.0.8`, no error is being returned. Furthermore, `iptables -j CONNMARK -h` returns

```
...
CONNMARK target options:
  --set-xmark value[/ctmask]    Zero mask bits and XOR ctmark with value
  --save-mark [--ctmask mask] [--nfmask mask]
                                Copy ctmark to nfmark using masks
  --restore-mark [--ctmask mask] [--nfmask mask]
                                Copy nfmark to ctmark using masks
  --set-mark value[/mask]       Set conntrack mark value
  --save-mark [--mask mask]     Save the packet nfmark in the connection
  --restore-mark [--mask mask]  Restore saved nfmark value
  --and-mark value              Binary AND the ctmark with bits
  --or-mark value               Binary OR  the ctmark with bits
  --xor-mark value              Binary XOR the ctmark with bits
```

indicating that this extension is compiled.

My operating system is Ubuntu-16.04 on Windows Subsystem for Linux 2, iptables version is
1.6.0-2ubuntu3.

Comment: Does `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m connmark --mark 0x0` work? If not, then it means that the kernel netfilter module for this feature is missing.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen You are right. WSL2 does not have it. The solution is to recompile WSL from  [source](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel) after enabling all CONNMARK-related modules in [config-wsl](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel/blob/linux-msft-wsl-5.15.y/Microsoft/config-wsl). Generic procedure is well described in this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/645131).